# How to get an array with all images numbers and images letters with regex?

Tags: php, regex

I need to get all concerned images parsing a html in PHP, based on an expression formatted like this:

`(fig. 8a-c, 9b-c)`

I would like to catch this using a regex in order to output an array such as:

```
array(
[8] => [a,b,c],
[9] => [b,c])
```

The expression can be anything like:

```
(fig. 8)
(fig. 8,9)
(fig. 11a, b)
```

Here is the regex i have at the moment, but it does not seem to work for every case:

https://regex101.com/r/ShqlnY/3/

Can you help me getting an array containing all included images ? Thanks

Comment: Note that it is not possible to match something that is not present in the input string. `a-c`  is not `a-b-c`.

Comment: Yes sure, but the rule would then be to interpolate the letter inbetween. If you have a clue on this as well... Thanks

Comment: @Max Did any of the answers work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use

```
'~(?:\G(?!^),\s*|\(fig\.)\s*\K([0-9]{1,3})([a-z]-[a-z])~'
```

with `preg_match_all` to get all the char ranges from inside a `(fig. ...)` substring (see the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3zl1nj/4)), and then use this post-process code:

```
$rx = "~(?:\G(?!^),\s*|\(fig\.)\s*\K([0-9]{1,3})([a-z]-[a-z])~";
$s = "(fig. 8a-c, 9b-c)";
preg_match_all($rx, $s, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE | PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

foreach ($matches as $m) {
    $result = [];
    $result[] = $m[0][1]; // Position of the match
    $result[] = $m[1][0]; // The number
    $kv = explode("-", $m[2][0]);
    $result = array_merge($result, buildNumChain($kv));
    print_r($result);
}

function buildNumChain($arr) {
    $ret = [];
    foreach(range($arr[0], $arr[1]) as $letter) {
        $ret[] = $letter;
    }
    return $ret;
}
```

Output:

```
Array ( [0] => 6  [1] => 8 [2] => a [3] => b [4] => c )
Array ( [0] => 12 [1] => 9 [2] => b [3] => c )
```

See the [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/Y5ls6).

**Regex details**

- `(?:\G(?!^),\s*|\(fig\.)` - `(fig.` or end of the previous match + `,` and 0+ whitespaces
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `\K` - match reset operator
- `([0-9]{1,3})` - Group 1: 1 to 3 digits
- `([a-z]-[a-z])` - Group 2: a lowercase letter, `-` and a lowercase letter.

Comment: Thanks a lot, then in your solution, how to associate number to letter ranges ? in order to have something like [8] => array([0]=>a [1]=>b [2] => c) ? Also i forgot to mention i need to get positions of the whole expression, so i will add PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE as a flag.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, i ended up with a regular expression like this:

```
'/(?:\(fig\.\h*|\G(?!^))(\d+)([a-z])?(?:-([a-z])?)?(?:,\h*)?(?=[^)]*\))/m'
```

used with `preg_match_all`

Comment: Note you can upvote the answers that helped you by clicking the UP arrow on the left.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps for your example data you might use a [range](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.range.php) and a pattern with 3 capturing groups where the third group is optional.

If the third group does not exists, you return the single value in an array, or else you use the second and the third group to create a range.

```
(?:^\(fig\.\h*|\G(?!^))(\d+)([a-z])(?:-([a-z])?)?(?:,\h*)?(?=[^)]*\))
```

- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `^\(fig\.\h*` Match start of the string and (fig. followed by 0+ horizonal whitespaces
  - `|` Or
  - `\G(?!^)` Assert position at the end of the previous match, not at the start
- `)` Close non capturing group
- `(\d+)([a-z])` Capture 1+ digits in group 1, Capture a-z in group 2
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `-([a-z])?`
- `)?` Close non capturing group and make optional
- `(?:,\h*)?` Match optional `,` and 0+ horizontal whitespace chars
- `(?=[^)]*\))` Assert what is on the right is a closing parenthesis

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rrDmI0/1)

For example:

```
$pattern = "/(?:^\(fig\.\h*|\G(?!^))(\d+)([a-z])(?:-([a-z])?)?(?:,\h*)?(?=[^)]*\))/m";
$str = '(fig. 8a-c, 9b-c)
(fig. 8)
(fig. 8,9)
(fig. 11a, b)';
preg_match_all($pattern, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER | PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE, 0);

$matches = array_map(function($x){
    if (isset($x[3][0])) {
        return [
            $x[1][0] => range($x[2][0], $x[3][0]),
            "start" => $x[1][1],
            "end" => $x[3][1]
        ];
    }
    return [
        $x[1][0] => [$x[2][1]],
        "start" => $x[2][0],
        "end" => $x[1][1]
    ];

}, $matches);

print_r($matches);
```

Result

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [8] => Array
                (
                    [0] => a
                    [1] => b
                    [2] => c
                )

            [start] => 6
            [end] => 9
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [9] => Array
                (
                    [0] => b
                    [1] => c
                )

            [start] => 12
            [end] => 15
        )

)
```

See a [php demo](https://3v4l.org/ln7VK)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, i am sorry i forgot to mention i need to retrieve the whole expression position as well using PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE, so how could i modify your solution in order to work with this constrain ?